# Do all open source web mapping platforms require programming?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, web-mapping, openlayers-2

I currently use a proprietary software product for my company's web mapping, however I am interested in seeing other products. I use QGIS and would like to to put my layers on the web for both internal (very large files - all roads in UK; all rivers in UK) and client based (small - 5-10 feature point/polygon files). From what I gather I need to use another platform (Leaflet, OpenLayes) in order to combine my layers into an online map with viewable attribute tables/searchable postcodes.

Do all of these platforms require JavaScript knowledge?  It seems like they all require coding of some sort and I cannot just 'upload' my shp files to an online server. If this is true, is one 'easier' than the rest?

Comment: I think if you want to just upload, you should look into ArcGIS Online or perhaps CartoDB.

Comment: I am looking for open source options.

Comment: CartoDB is open source, and is probably the easiest option to create clickable, searchable web maps.  You will just need a paid subscription to upload anything more than a few small layers.  If you're looking for free open source options, then Leaflet is the way to go.  Take a quick web course on JavaScript (w3scools, Codecademy) and you'll be set.  Leaflet is very easy to pick up.

Comment: Do you have to pay to store large datasets on Leaflet?

Comment: Leaflet is just the framework used to serve the data.  Your data is stored on a web server, whether it be your own local server or a remote hosted server you pay for.

Comment: Is QGIS Server an example of a web server?

Comment: Here's an [explanation of web servers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/What_is_a_web_server) from Mozilla.  I've never used QGIS Server, so I'm not sure what it's capable of as far as serving your data online, but it looks like it can do quite a bit for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29937/discussion-between-bowman01-and-blakeg).

Comment: To return to the original question, yes, libraries written in Javascript generally require Javascript knowledge to get beyond anything but the most basic interface. Learning Javascript is never going to be anything but advantageous in web mapping.

Answer (score 1):

If you will use qgis-server than you can use qgis-web-client:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Web-Client

or lizmap-web-client:

https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client

Both will give you a "out of the box" Webmapping-client

If you want to adapt functionalities then you will have to start programming.